# I am getting Error: Project ID is required deploying to ropsten in truffle

Tags: truffle, ropsten

I am getting the following error:

Error: PollingBlockTracker -
encountered an error while attempting to update latest block:

Error: project ID is required

at C:\Users\myuser\Code Projects\sdfsd\node_modules@trufflesuite\web3-provider-engine\subproviders\provider.js:18:36

```
ropsten: {
  provider: new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://ropsten.infura.io/2d26d6e3bafb42bfa4fa8cc248350d00"),
  network_id: 3,
  gas: 4000000
}
```

Comment: Make up your mind, is it ropsten or mainnet???

Comment: And what is "myropstenidhere"? Infura requires an Infura project ID!

Comment: Sorry it's Ropsten made the corrections and put in the Infura Project ID.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things you have to fix

- Provider should be a function that returns the provider, and not the provider directly. Check [truffle's documentation](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration#providers).

```
ropsten: {
  provider: function () {
    return new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "URL");
  },
  network_id: 3,
  gas: 4000000
}
```

- Once you have registered with Infura they will provide an URL for your project. For ropsten the URL starts with `https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/`, for example `https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/123456789`. Sea [Infura docs](https://infura.io/docs/gettingStarted/chooseaNetwork) for others networks or protocols supported.